# Javascript add ID and hash link to new ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

I "learned" JavaScript a few months ago but quickly picked up Python and spent the past few months writing programs in that language, so I decided it would be a good idea to go back and actually *learn* JavaScript. Right now I'm making a very simple "blog" with JS that takes the title of the post, generates a hash link from the post, and creates a **recent posts** section where you can click the link to jump to the post in the page.

For instance, say one of the posts is formatted like this:

```
<h2 class="post">Another post for you</h2>
<h4>I know you love these</h4>
```

With multiple posts, and an empty container at the bottom, which will be used to append the recent posts links:

```
<div id="get-post"></div>
```

My JS code basically grabs each title with the `post` class and creates a hash link from the element's title (removing spaces and commas). It then creates and appends a text node consisting of the post title, and then appends the entire link into the `get-post` container.

```
var postList = $('#get-post');
var post = $('.post');

function generateRecentPosts() {
    post.each(function() {
        // Create link from post title that will be used to
        // access that post.
        var postLink = document.createElement('a');
        // Create text node from post title that will be appended
        // to the postLink.
        var text = document.createTextNode($(this).html());

        // Add elements to the DOM.
        postLink.href = createLocalLink($(this));
        postLink.appendChild(text);
        postList.append(postLink);
        postList.append('<br />');
    });
}

function createLocalLink(elm) {
    // Creates the href link that will be used to go to a blog post.
    // For example, if the title of the elm parameter is "My Post",
    // a link is created called #My-Post that will be used to access
    // that post.
    elm.id = elm.html().replace(/,/g, '').replace(/\s/g, '-');
    console.log(elm.id); // Make sure the ID is added.
    return '#' + elm.id;
}

generateRecentPosts();
```

My problem is that the links it generates to not point to the ID created for each title. When I click on the link, I can see that it successfully created the href hash `#My-Post` and added it to the anchor tag, but it doesn't take me to the post title.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/samrap/GQtxL/

I even added a console log function to make sure the ID is being added to the title as I thought that was the problem, but it isn't because the console is printing the correct new ID. I could really use some help in figuring out where exactly the problem is here.

Comment: Please post an example of a post that is appended and its corresponding link, also, you should probably use `text()` and not `html()` for generating the id to avoid potentially inserting special characters

Comment: added a jsfiddle example with text() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `h2` tags need to have an `id` or `name` attribute that corresponds with the link, that is what makes internal links work. The `id` is not getting added because you are accessing a jQuery object as if it were a DOM node (`elm.id = ...`). Modify your `createLocalLink` function to use jQuery's `attr` method to set the `id` property:

```
elm.attr('id', elm.html().replace(/,/g, '').replace(/\s/g, '-'));
```

Additionally, since you have jQuery available you could whittle your code down to:

```
var $this = $(this),
    link = createLocalLink($this);

var $postLink = $('a', {
    text: $this.text(),
    href: link
})

postList.append($postLink).append('<br />');
```

Here is your fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/GQtxL/1/

Comment: That's what I thought I was doing in this line of `createLocalLink()`: `elm.id = elm.html().replace(/,/g, '').replace(/\s/g, '-');` ?

Comment: Saw the problem, updated my answer. You are using `.id`, should be `attr('id', ...)`

Comment: Thanks for that, also, I read that it is slower using jq to create elements, is it much of a difference?

Comment: It isn't slower and in fact can be faster depending on the operation and the method you use to create elements (mostly because jQuery uses createDocumentFragment to minimize reflow (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createDocumentFragment)

Comment: Thanks for the info, one more thing: Out of curiosity, why does `.id` not work? Is it not compatible when the jq lib is implemented?

Comment: Because jQuery doesn't return a DOM node (where this would be applicable), it returns a reference to the jQuery object which will accept an `id` property but will not tie it to the DOM node(s) it contains. You can use `$(selector).get(0)` or `$(selector)[0]` for direct access to the DOM node

Answer (score 1):

This is because your link uses the href = "#My-Post" but none of the posts has the ID "My-Post". It only has a class "post".

This happens because the argument that your are passing to the createLocalLink() function is a DOM Node. But by doing elm.id you are not changing the DOM property but adding another property to the "elm" object. Thus your "elm" object is

```
x.fn.x.init[1]
0: h2.post
context: h2.post
id: "Another-post-for-you"
length: 1
__proto__: Object[0]
```

Thus the actual post never gets the attribute ID only "elm" object gets it. Note the empty ID attribute below

```
draggable: false
firstChild: text
firstElementChild: null
hidden: false
id: ""
innerHTML: "Another post for you"
innerText: "Another post for you"
```

Thus your document has no element with the ID "My-Post". You can view the source of your HTML to verify this.

For internal links to work there should be an element with the same ID as that used in the href attribute of the link.

For example

```
<div id="post1">
 Your Post Here
</div>

<!--just to show the effect of moving to the post-->
<div style="clear:both; height:900px"></div>

<a href = "#post1">Click Here</a>
```

This would work because there is an element with the id "post1" and the link uses the href "#post1" which links it to the corresponding  element. Hence, add the corresponding id to your post as well (other than your link) for it to work.

Comment: That's what I thought I was doing in this line of `createLocalLink()`: `elm.id = elm.html().replace(/,/g, '').replace(/\s/g, '-');` ?

Answer (score 0):

In function `createLocalLink` you are using `elm` argument as dom node, but actually passing a jQuery wrapped object to it, which don't have `id` property. To get it work, use `elm.get(0).id = ...` or `elm.attr('id', elm.text().replace(/,/g, '').replace(/\s/g, '-'););`